# PHP + MySQL + HTML Displaying Different information onTable

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a query that I am going to display as a table. But I would like the integer value within my table to be displayed as something else within the table.

For example:

Thw query will display Product ID, and Product completion. 
Production completion within my table is stored as either 1 or 0.

So in the table, I would have instead of a 1 or 0, a "yes" or "no" respectively.

How can I do this?

Simple I know, but I have been searching to no avail. I'm sure its because I don't know what the term is for what I'm looking to do.

I'm almost certain this has been asked before, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: At what stage are you in completing this? Have you written the code to run the query and display the output yet? If so can you paste it in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just trying to display "Yes" or "No" then I would use a ternary operator.

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th> 
      <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?=$var == 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No'?></td>
      <td>Col 2 data</td> 
      <td>Col 3 data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The ternary operator says, if `$var==1` display `Yes` else display `No`.

Comment: Thank you, this was easy to implement and exactly what I wanted to do, Sorry my question was so open ended

Answer (score 2):

There is alot of unknows with this question.
But assuming you have queried the database and have a value returned
and all you need to do is switch 0 and 1 to yes or no then you can just do an if statement and insert that into the table.

```
  // assuming $value = 1 
  <td><?php if($value){echo "yes";}else{echo "No";}?></td>
```

or have it in whatever format you want

Answer (score 1):

There are many good answers to choose from, that have been given.

This is one/another way of doing this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM your_table");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

        $column = $row['ID'];
        if ($column == "1") {

        $column = "Yes";
               echo $column;
            }

        else{

            $column = "No";

               echo $column;

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting a result into a variable, and using it with an IF statememt is a solution.
A boolean variable can be hardcoded all right. 
If the boolean is TRUE you echo a Yes or else a NO.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you out a little, depending on how far you are. This assumes you are using mysqli and that your connection string has a variable of $con (adjust as needed)

```
<?php

$sql="select product_id, product_completion from tbl";
$sql_result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

?>

<table>

    <tr>
        <th>Product ID</th>
        <th>Completed</th>
    </tr>

<?php $z=0; while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_result)) { ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['product_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php if ($row['product_completion'] == 1) echo 'yes'; else echo 'no'; ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php $z++; } ?>

</table>
```

Also change your query to your actual query and the column names to your actual column names, and "tbl" to you actual table name, etc.